# What are good OpenGL ES 1.x practices?

Tags: opengl-es

I just started working with OpenGL ES within Android but I suppose this could also go for other mobile platforms that use OpenGL ES. I've gone over a few tutorials to get me started but I feel like there are various things that I am missing.

For instance is it good practice to have objects draw themselves individually? I have a cube object which draws itself, then I have a "panel" object which is an array of 10x10 cubes, and finally another object which consist of panels to create a cube like object. I have 7500 cubes that need to be drawn, though each one being very "small". Here's what the drawing function looks like:

```
public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, verticesBuffer);

    gl.glColor4f(rgba[0], rgba[1], rgba[2], rgba[3]);

    gl.glTranslatef(x, y, z);
    gl.glRotatef(rx, 1, 0, 0);
    gl.glRotatef(ry, 0, 1, 0);
    gl.glRotatef(rz, 0, 0, 1);

    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, numOfIndices,
                    GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indicesBuffer);

    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
}
```

Are there any other things which one should avoid when dealing with OpenGL ES?

Edit: Another thing I have been wondering, is it good practice to reduce the amount of calls to certain methods, such as

```
gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);

gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
```

This is called for every object when drawn, is it a necessity or can it be called once in my upper most object once?

Also:

```
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

I realize that enabling and disabling may be necessary depending on situation but if it can be avoided, will this not adversely affect anything?

Comment: Can't you call gl.glDrawElements after you have looped through every object?

Comment: It may be possible by adding all of the vertices and indices into one array? I'm not entirely sure but because glDrawElements requires you to feed it the indices of each triangle to draw you would need to group them all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a batcher to batch all the vertices into one array and then draw, thus using only one draw call.

EDIT: Here is an example from my project. I have several NPCs that I need to draw and update individually so that they move independently from one another.

```
// update
    for (int i = 0; i < npcs.length; i++) {
        npcs[i].update(touchEvents);
    }

    // draw
    npcBatcher.beginBatch(Assets.atlas);
    for (int i = 0; i < npcs.length; i++) {
        npcs[i].draw(npcBatcher);
    }
    npcBatcher.endBatch();
```

In my draw method I begin the batch, add to the batch and finally end the batch (which does the actually drawing). In the update method, I loop through each NPC object and update EACH NPC. In the update method for NPC object I randomly generate a few numbers and move them according to the random number (do all the logic that makes them behave differently). Since each NPC has their own update with random generated numbers, they all act differently. All the drawing is done at once. The drawing all at once does not matter, it is the update for each object that matters and is what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry, would batching allow for the exact positioning of the vertices? Say I needed a cube to be rotated, or do I need to directly change said vertices to correspond to the on screen positions?

Comment: I don't see why you would need to change your vertices. Once you submit them, you can call glRotate() or glTranslate. Batching just allows you to add all your vertices together and draw them all with just one draw call compared to multiple calls that may hinder your performace.

Comment: What I meant is that, currently everything is created around (0,0,0) and then rotated or translated into place, each time it is draw. I realize this is probably bad practice. So what I'm asking is should I do the rotation and translating before hand putting the vertices exactly where I want and avoiding the extra overhead. That's the only way I can see batch drawing working properly.

Comment: In my experience that is how it has always been done. Say you had a space ship drawn at (10, 10) and it needs to move 10 units on the x axis. You wouldn't change the vertices from (each vertex) (10, 10) to (20, 10) but instead would translate it 10 units. You could always copy the current default matrix via glPushMatrix() and do your drawing after the push so that nothing else is affected except for whatever code is after the push matrix call. Then just glPopMatrix().

Comment: I am familiar with glPushMatrix and glPopMatrix and do use them for my current drawing. What confuses me is, how would I go about grouping all of the vertices together to be drawn yet still be able to manipulate their positions individual?

Comment: First batch everything. Second add a rotate/translate/scale or whatever method you need in your object class. Then call each of their update methods so that they move individually.

Comment: Would you mind writing some pseudo code? I'm sorry if this seems trivial, but I don't quite understand how that can work. How would I move anything individually if they are all drawn at the same time? From the way I understand you, you first need to rotate/translate the matrix and then draw your objects so that they appear in place. If all the vertices are in one array, a rotate/translate will move them all at the same time, not individually. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not expert but I have tried to understand your problem and give a solution. I have edited my post with some simple pseudo code and explanation.

Comment: Ok, so from what I get from your code is that each NPC/Object is still calling glDrawElements with it's own float buffers. Meaning that each object is still calling glRotate/glTranslate for itself. The only difference I see in your code compared to mine is that the rotation/translation would be done all together in your update and then its all drawn together. Wouldn't the fact that you are changing the Matrix for each rotation/translation affect all of the other objects as you are drawing them after all of that is done? Thank you for all your responses.

Comment: On close inspection, I see that I am actually manipulating the vertices, opposite of what I had said earlier... SO, in a sense you are correct. They are all calling their own float buffers but not glDrawElements. Where you see npcs[i].drawSprite(batcher), all that is doing is ADDING the vertices to the main buffer. Where you see batcher.endBatch(), THAT is calling the glDrawArray/Elements.

Comment: Ah, ok! Yeah, that clears it up and makes sense to me now. Thanks for clearing that up and being so responsive.

Comment: Sorry I had confused you earlier. Glad you understood what is actually going on =]

Comment: No worries, like you said, proves I wasn't that far off in my understanding. Thanks again for being helpful.

Answer (score 1):

your opengl es performance is highly depend upon your number of gl calls,
so try to reduce the gl calls.
If its your only place to draw, there is no need to disable cullface and vertex array every time and put your enabling calls of cull face in initialization method only so that it will enables only once.

Comment: Ok, so there's no need to disable options once activated unless I enable something that directly conflicts?